# When Javascript objects are garbage collected from memory?

Tags: javascript, memory-management

I have seen similar threads on this QnA, but my specific scenario is as below.

```
function render(canvas) {
    var renderer = new Renderer(canvas);
    renderer.render();
}
```

`Renderer.render()` draws some stuff on the `<canvas>`. Now the thing is that this works, so this means instance `renderer` is not garbage collected. This brings me to my question - when will `renderer` be garbage collected? Note that this object is referred nowhere else, except by its own methods.

I would like that object to be garbage collected when it finishes rendering. Is there any way to force that?

Comment: How do you know that `renderer` is **not** garbage collected after the function goes out of scope?

Comment: Had been that, then it should have stopped rendering as soon as it goes out of scope. That effectively means that it couldn't possibly have rendered anything.

Comment: Oh yes and I should add that `render()` is not going to render immediately. It sort of queues that and sets `setTimeout` to run afterwards to process the queue. This is a trick to prevent the browser from locking up while it is rendering.

Comment: You seem to know or presume to know a lot about the implementation of your JS engine and its thread model in particular. It would stand to reason that the `Renderer::render()` function starts a new thread holding a reference to itself, and once the thread finishes there would be no more references and all is well... I mean, why are you worrying about this? Do you have reason to suspect a memory leak?

Comment: Yes. Actually `Renderer` is pretty 'heavy'. I would like to be sure that it doesn't lay around when it is not needed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your timeout in `render()` holds a reference to a function, which in turn holds a reference to the renderer. Once the timeout has executed, and provided it doesn't set any more timeouts, there is no reference to the function, and there is no reference to the renderer, so it is clear to be garbage collected.

Answer (score 1):

in v8 way, There is no references of the object, and javascript engine become idle.

Answer (score 1):

The details of garbage collection are not defined by the ECMAScript specification, so implementations are different in different browsers, but usually in JavaScript an object becomes available for garbage collection when there are no remaining references to it.

In the case of your example, it will be when the function in which `renderer` is declared returns.

Comment: The `render` function is most likely asynchronous and starts a new thread or something like that.

Comment: Yes. That's why I asked this question.

Comment: @Kerrek SB - that is possible, but in any case, once no references remain to the `renderer` object it will be available for garbage collection.